# Remove multi-elements from an arraylist error

Tags: java

```
    public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws supernova, autowin{
 ArrayList<Integer> integer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 integer.add(new Integer(0));
 integer.add(new Integer(1));
 integer.add(new Integer(2));

 integer.add(new Integer(3));
 System.out.println(integer.get(0));
 System.out.println(integer.get(1));

 System.out.println(integer.size());
 for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){
     if(i == integer.get(i)){integer.remove(i);System.out.println("remove");}
 }
 System.out.println(integer.get(0));
 System.out.println(integer.get(1));
 System.out.println(integer.size());
 }
```

The outputs are 
0
1
4
remove
1
2
3
.I expect this code to remove two elements(0 and 1),but it eventually only remove the first element. What if I want to remove all elements that have a special feature ,speaking like all elements store a odd number ,from an arraylist.
Could you explain the reason? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to format your code, and also make sure it's a [mcve]. In particular we don't know what `supernova` or `autowin` are, but they don't seem to be relevant here. Add the imports, rename your class to follow Java naming conventions etc.

Comment: The easy trick for removing elements when iterating by element index is to go in reverse: `for(int i = 2;i>=0;i--){`. This avoids skipping the next element when you remove one. (Of course, it is better to use an `Iterator`)

Comment: The elements have already shifted after the first deletion.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `remove` method, all elements ahead of the index are moved to the left. Therefore, after the first element is removed, `i == integer.get(i)` will always be false, because the `Integer`'s value was set to be its original index, but now they are all "one ahead", so to speak.

Use a debugger in an IDE to see the process happen.

Answer (score 0):

Lets go step by step:

in `for` loop, when `i = 0`, you remove value from `arraylist` on position `0`. Now, your ArrayList will be `1,2,3`. Now, you check position `i = 1`, and in that position you have `2`, not `1`. because `2` is not equal to `1`, `if` will not be executed.

One solution would be to change the direction of the `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 1;i >= 0;i--){
     if(i == integer.get(i)) {integer.remove(i);System.out.println("remove");}
 }
```

Now, the output will be:

```
0
1
4
remove
remove
2
3
2
```

**Update: OP asked new question**

If you want to remove odd numbers, just place logic for it in if:

```
for(int i = integer.size() - 1;i >= 0;i--){
     if(integer.get(i) % 2 != 0 {
         integer.remove(i);
         System.out.println("remove");
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What if I want to remove all elements that have a special feature ,speaking like all elements store a odd number ,from an arraylist.

Comment: Please, update your question with what you asked here in comment in order to be by the rules

Answer (score 0):

After the first iteration **(i=0)** the list is modified and becomes to

> [1, 2, 3]

then for the next iteration i=1 adn then you do

```
if (i == integer.get(i)) {
```

`if 1 == elementAtIndex1`--> `if 1==2` wich returns false an is not removing anything....

therefore your code is behaving like that...